# Regular expressions preg_split

Tags: php, regex, laravel, codeigniter, preg-split

Regular expression - need to split the word using `preg_split`

```
----------------------- Page 1-----------------------
text of page 1


----------------------- Page 2-----------------------
text of page 2


----------------------- Page 3-----------------------
 text of page 3
```

I need to explode each page text into an array.

```
array( [0]=> "text of page 1", [1] => "text of page 2",[2]=>"text of page 3")
```

I used the following regex

```
((7[-])(page)( )[1-100](7[-]))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this, assuming that there will always be one space before `P` and after `e`, and that there is no space between the number and the `-`s.

```
\s*-+ Page \d+-+\n
```

- `\s*` matches the trailing whitespace from the previous page.
- `-+ Page \d+-+` matches the `--------- Page x-----------` line
- `\n` so that each split has no leading new lines.

Note that the first element of the split array will be an empty string or whitespace, and can be discarded.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xBAV3c/1)